# asp.net dynamic styling missing min-height

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I am trying to build a stylle sheet dynamically (based on certain business rules) Long story short it mostly works, except there is one css tag I cannot set min-height. I can hit height, but not min-height. both being valid css values

i.e

```
string h = "105mm";
Style dynamicClassStyle = new Style();
dynamicClassStyle.Height = new Unit(h);
Page.Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(dynamicClassStyle, null, ".make-display");
```

That renders a height tag alright, but what i really need is a min-height. i would love to be able to go

```
dynamicClassStyle.Min-Height = new Unit(h);
```

in order to get this

```
.make-display {
  min-height:90mm;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to

1. inherit from [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.aspx),
2. add a **MinHeight** property and
3. override [FillStyleAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.fillstyleattributes.aspx) to handle your new property.
4. You can then use an instance of this new (min-height aware) **MinHeightStyle** (instead of Style) in your own code.

The new class:

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class MinHeightStyle : Style
{
    public Unit MinHeight
    {
        get
        {
            var minHeight = this.ViewState["MinHeight"];

            if (minHeight != null)
            {
                return (Unit)minHeight;
            }

            return Unit.Empty;
        }

        set
        {
            this.ViewState["MinHeight"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void FillStyleAttributes(CssStyleCollection attributes, IUrlResolutionService urlResolver)
    {
        base.FillStyleAttributes(attributes, urlResolver);

        if (!this.MinHeight.IsEmpty)
        {
            attributes.Add("min-height", this.MinHeight.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And your new code:

```
string h = "105mm";
MinHeightStyle dynamicClassStyle = new MinHeightStyle();
dynamicClassStyle.Height = new Unit(h);
dynamicClassStyle.MinHeight = new Unit(h);
Page.Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(dynamicClassStyle, null, ".make-display");
```

Which renders the following:

```
.make-display { min-height:105mm;height:105mm; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Style class does not conatin a property named as `Min-Height`. Checkout the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) link, so you can't add one.

Comment: microsoft fail....... are there any alternatives i could use to acheive the same result